# Facebook Needs the JSON php extension?>

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to use FB login. I have used the same code for other websites and it works fine. But  only one domain it returns a fatal error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught 'Exception' with message 'Facebook needs the
>   JSON PHP extension' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/base_facebook.php:22 Stack trace
>    /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/facebook.php:18 require_once()#1 ....

Answer (score 2):

Facebook needs the [JSON PHP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.requirements.php) installed on your server.

You will need to talk to the server administrator and ask them to install the extension for you.